# WPF Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.Windows.Documents.Fixed.FormatProviders.Pdf.Model.Types.PdfLiteralString'

Tags: wpf

I am working on WPF with telerik RADPDFfixedDcoument

I am getting invalid cast error on below code

```
var file = new FileStream(_physicalpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

RadFixedDocument documentX = new PdfFormatProvider().Import(file);// this line throws error
```

> Error:Unable to cast object of type
>   'Telerik.Windows.Documents.Fixed.FormatProviders.Pdf.Model.Types.PdfLiteralString'
>   to type
>   'Telerik.Windows.Documents.Fixed.FormatProviders.Pdf.Model.Elements.Destinations.DestinationObject'.

Comment: tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164826/can-i-use-telerik-document-processing-to-read-pdf-content but itself got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named destinations in PDF are not supported by Telerik yet.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/view-ticket?threadid=1175433 for more details.